Detecting a narrowing conversion using template metaprogramming
I'm implementing a class template that models a quantity as follows:
template<typename T>
class Quantity{

private:
    T m_val{};

public:
    // A simple getter
    T value() const{ return m_val; }

    //Quantity Constructor:
    template<typename R>
    Quantity(const Quantity<R>& otherQty){

        m_val = otherQty.value();

    }

};

Obviously in the constructor I'm doing a conversion from type 'R' to type 'T'. I want to add a static_assert there to check that R is convertible to T without causing a narrowing conversion. Is there already a metafunction/type_trait to do so? If not, how can I implement my own?

Changing the constructor to Quantity(const Quantity<R>& otherQty) : m_val{ otherQty.value() } {} should do the job, since brace-enclosed initializers disallow narrowing conversions.
